# How to redirect more than one output line into a text file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

At the moment I have

```
echo ping %id% > 1.bat
```

But I want to copy more than one line of code into another file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo first line >1.txt
echo second line >>1.txt
echo third line >>1.txt
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea it was that simple!

Comment: Key to remember here is that with one "re-direct" ">" it will over-write the resulting txt file: 1.txt.  With two "re-directs" ">>" it will append or add to the 1.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 - (same as what Stephan posted)

```
echo first line >1.bat
echo second line >>1.bat
```

Option 2

```
>1.bat (
  echo first line
  echo second line
)
```

Option 3

```
call :output >1.bat
exit /b

:output
echo first line
echo second line
exit /b
```

Options 2 and 3 are significantly faster than option 1 if you are writing lots of output because they only have to open and position the stream pointer once, whereas option 1 must open and position for each line.